# Want to use NIntegrate with some unknown coefficients associated with the expressions

Tags: numerical-integration

```
NIntegrate[C*x^2, {x, 0, 2}]
```

Here is the simple expression I want to use `NIntegrate` to find the value, but I am getting "The integrand C x^2 has evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling points in the region with boundaries {{0,2}}." this error. How to overcome this. **I dont want to use `Integrate`**.

Why I am not using Integrate is, Suppose if I have 'n' terms in my expressions associated with 'n' unknown coefficients, Then Integrate takes a lot of time to get the result.

*(The integrand I am interested in has 70 terms, and `Integrate` takes too much time in this case)*

---

It is not a complete answer, but I can say I have solved 50% problem suppose if we have an expression

```
exp = Expand[C1* Sin[x] + C2*Cos[x]]
exp1 = Expand[(D[exp, {x, 2}])^2]
Expand[N[Integrate[exp1, {x, 0, 2}]]](*Regular integral result*)
s = CoefficientList[exp1, {C1, C2}]
MatrixForm[s]
Flatten[NIntegrate[s, {x, 0, 2}]](*Numerical integration result*)
```

But how to put it back to original form?

Comment: why not just `C NIntegrate[x^2, {x, 0, 2}]`?

Comment: Please be aware of the fact that `C` is reserved in Mma. Use, say, `c`.

Comment: The error message is pretty informative: `C` is **not a number** so of course `NIntegrate[]` will be unable to evaluate numerically.

Comment: I know that, but I want the the result in terms of c at the end

Comment: In which case `NIntegrate[]` is the wrong function. You haven't explained why `Integrate[]` is not useful for you, so there isn't much else to say.

Comment: Actually, I put a small expression,  In my code, there are (Ci, i=1...70) its a pretty big expression I don't want to use integrate as you know it takes too much time.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Collect`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Collect) where the 3rd argument performs your integration:

```
Collect[c x^2, c, NIntegrate[#, {x, 0, 2}]&]
```

> 2.66667 c

For your second example:

```
expr = D[c1 Sin[x] + c2 Cos[x], x, x]^2
Collect[expr, c1|c2, NIntegrate[#, {x, 0, 2}]&]
```

> (-c2 Cos[x] - c1 Sin[x])^2
>
> 1.1892 c1^2 + 0.826822 c1 c2 + 0.810799 c2^2

Another possibility is to use an inactive integral, distribute, then integrate. This way you perform 3 simple integrals instead of 1 complicated integral. The inactive integral:

```
integral = Inactive[Integrate][Expand @ expr, {x, 0, 2}]
```

> Inactive[Integrate][(c2^2 Cos[x]^2 + 2 c1 c2 Cos[x] Sin[x] + 
>      c1^2 Sin[x]^2), {x, 0, 2}]

Use [`Distribute`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Distribute), then activate:

```
N @ Activate @ Distribute @ integral
```

> 1.1892 c1^2 + 0.826822 c1 c2 + 0.810799 c2^2

Answer (score 0):

Note: Capitals are reserved in Mathematica, so use small letters!!

Don't use "NIntegrate" directly, Make it as a function of constant coefficients, then It will work.

See this:

```
 f[c_] := NIntegrate[c*x^2, {x, 0, 2}]
 f[1.]
```

2.66667

another example:

```
 f[c_, d_] := NIntegrate[c*x^2 + d*x, {x, 0, 2}]
 f[1., 2.]
```

6.66667

Comment: I looking for an answer in terms of C, I do not know the value of  C aprior.

Comment: @vijay, Here you are putting the value of c after evaluating the integral. Note that, "NIntegrate" is a numerical operation, Hence numerically you can't get a parametric answer, This is not possible!!.